# Combobox.SelectedValue wont select the actual value

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a problem that I'm struggling with.

I fill a combobox this way:

```
RDTA_cb_provincias.DataSource = provincias;
RDTA_cb_provincias.DisplayMember = IdiomaBD.ObjCI.ToString().Equals("eu-ES")
    ? "TTEXNOMBRPROV_EU"
    : "TTEXNOMBRPROV_ES";
RDTA_cb_provincias.ValueMember = "TCODIDTERRITORIO";
```

There's some stuff depending on the language of the user, but i guess that's not important here.

Well, when i want to select depending on the value  member i do this:

```
RDTA_cb_provincias.SelectedValue = provincia2.TCODIDTERRITORIO;
```

But for some reason it won't show up the actual item I want to show. While debugging i can see that RDTA_cb_provincias.SelectedValue matches provincia2.TCODIDTERRITORIO.

For example, I've set SelectedValue to 51, but when i see the SelectedItem inside the ComboBox once I've changed the value, It shows up an object that has 47 as its TCODIDTERRITORIO.

What can it be? Or how can I bypass this problem (Maybe iterating the whole ComboBox item list until i find the one i want to select?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SelectedItem` instead:

```
RDTA_cb_provincias.SelectedItem = provincia2;
```

Or you can use `SelectedIndex` as follows:

```
RDTA_cb_provincias.SelectedIndex = RDTA_cb_provincias.FindStringExact(provincia2.TCODIDTERRITORIO)
```

Comment: That `SelectedIndex` lookup is a bad idea; it won't work if there are duplicate strings. And, shouldn't that `SelectedItem` be the main object `provincia2`, and not its property?

Comment: @Nyerguds in this case of province code Id that will not happen, but you are right, Thank you for your feedback